# androidpublisher inappproducts error 400 inAppProductInvalidPrice

Tags: google-play

I'm trying to update the prices of each country for a certain sku:

```
[['sku', 'country', 'currency', 'price']]
['apples_30', 'KE', 'KES', 300.0]
['apples_30', 'LK', 'LKR', 475.0]
['apples_30', 'US', 'USD', 2.99]
['apples_30', 'LV', 'EUR', 3.39]
['apples_30', 'CA', 'CAD', 3.99]
['apples_30', 'TZ', 'TZS', 6500.0]
['apples_30', 'KH', 'USD', 2.99]
['apples_30', 'MX', 'MXN', 55.0]
['apples_30', 'HR', 'HRK', 26.0]...
```

I am using the inappproducts().update() method with these parameters:

```
request = pubapi.inappproducts().update(packageName=package_name, sku = 'apples_30', body = testbody)
result = request.execute()
```

using this testbody:

```
{'packageName': 'com.package.name',
 'prices': {'CA': {'currency': 'CAD', 'priceMicros': '3600000'},
  'HR': {'currency': 'HRK', 'priceMicros': '11390000'},
  'KE': {'currency': 'KES', 'priceMicros': '300000000'},
  'KH': {'currency': 'USD', 'priceMicros': '2990000'},
  'LK': {'currency': 'LKR', 'priceMicros': '314730000'},
  'LV': {'currency': 'EUR', 'priceMicros': '1460000'},
  'MX': {'currency': 'MXN', 'priceMicros': '26580000'},
  'TZ': {'currency': 'TZS', 'priceMicros': '6500000000'},
  'US': {'currency': 'USD', 'priceMicros': '2990000'}},
 'sku': 'apples_30'}
```

My problem is I'm getting this error.

> {'code': 400, 'errors': [{'message': 'Invalid price {0}.', 'domain':
>   'androidpublisher', 'reason': 'inAppProductInvalidPrice'}], 'message':
>   'Invalid price {0}.'}

I understand this is self-explanatory, but I don't get why this is an invalid price when I'm using the same format as what I got from the inappproducts().list() method:

```
{'sku': 'apples_30', 
'prices': {'KE': {'priceMicros': '200000000', 'currency': 'KES'}, 
           'LK': {'priceMicros': '150000000', 'currency': 'LKR'}, 
           'US': {'priceMicros': '990000', 'currency': 'USD'}, 
           'LV': {'priceMicros': '1090000', 'currency': 'EUR'}, 
           'CA': {'priceMicros': '1290000', 'currency': 'CAD'},...
```

If anyone can point me to the right direction, that'd be great! Really need help. Documentation is seriously lacking. :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

nvm. figured it out. you have to use the whole resource representation as the request body. here it is: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts#resource